# Can assigning an out value be avoided?

Tags: c#, roslyn

My question is theoretical, please do not suggest code edits or alternatives.

I have a method as follows:

```
private bool SomeMethod(int D, out SomeStruct SXY) {

    if (D<0) {
         return false;
    }

    SXY = new SomeStruct(D);
    return true;
}
```

And I consume this method in the following way:

```
if (true) {
    SomeStruct SXY; // Local scope, not used anywhere else.
    if (SomeMethod(12, out SXY)) {
        // Use SXY only when it has a meaningful value
    }
}
```

The compiler is complaining about the SXY out value not being assigned before return in SomeMethod.

Can we avoid the useless assignment and struct creation in SomeMethod when it is obvious - I would assume, even for the compiler - that the SXY will only be used if it is meaningful?
Could the code analysis go deep enough to allow compile in the above situation?

**Edit:**

Freggar asked for it, the actual code I used in production is like:

```
private SomeStruct? SomeMethod(int D) {

    if (D < 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return new SomeStruct(D);
}
```

Called as:

```
if (true) {
    SomeStruct? SXY = SomeMethod(12);
    if (SXY != null) {
        // Use SXY only when it is not null
    }
}
```

Again, this is just a simplified code to demonstrate the gist of it. SomeMethod is more complex and may return with null at multiple places, also calling it is different. My purpose was to understand why Roslyn cannot tell if SomeMethod can safely return without SXY being assigned.

Comment: I think C#7 feature will fit your requirements: `if (SomeMethod(12, out SomeStruct SXY)` .

Comment: @Pepito Is your concern the requirement to assign a value so that `SomeMethod()` compiles (i.e. in `if (D<0) {` you also need to assign a value)? Or is the concern the unused local scope variable?

Comment: @Fabio that isn't really any different from the example OP provided in terms of the unused local scope variable.

Comment: @john: I would like to avoid a variable creation and related overhead.

Comment: You shouldn't be concerend with overhead. As for the variable creation, after the method has returned, the  `out` parameter will *always* have a valid value (i.e. it will be initialized) and therefore the scope of the variable will also be outside the if. You could manually scope your variable by using a `{}` Block but this seems more like a code smell to me.

Comment: *SXY will only be used if it is meaningful* How can the code check if SXY is meaningful if it is undefined?

Comment: @John and how does the code know that undefined isn't meaningful?

Comment: @Freggar: The overhead is primarily in memory consumption. I did manually scope my variable, hence the if (true) {...}

Comment: @John Wu: the meaningfulness is determined by the return value of SomeMethod.

Comment: What about returning `SomeStruct?` instead and just returning `null` when the answer is No.

Comment: It sounds like the compile is telling you not to run with scissors, but you're saying that you want to run with scissors. I suspect the compiler knows what is safer.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen: Yes, this is my solution to the current coding challenge, however the question still remains if Roslyn could detect this issue.

Comment: @Pepito If you were Rosyln, how would _you_ detect the "issue"?

Comment: By csharp specification you can achieve it (I mean does not set out struct) if this struct is accessibility by source and doesn't have any state (doesn't have any fields). (If your struct is accessibility by metadata you actually can achieve it with more less conditions)

Comment: Note that in C# 7 you can just use a discard: `if (SomeMethod(12, out _))`. There's no need for a variable at the source code level at all. There's still the "overhead" in that the compiler will generate IL as if you'd declared a variable, but I wouldn't worry about it unless you have actual evidence that it's important.

Comment: Also note that you don't need `if (true)` to declare a new scope. Just use a block on its own.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: _ is not a solution for the current case as the problem IS in the method, not how I call it. Re scope, I know { } is enough without if(true).

Comment: @PepitoSh: It's really unclear to me what the problem is at all. You've sometimes talked about scope, sometimes talked about memory and allocation, and then said those aren't the problem. The C# language specification is clear: `out` parameters must be definitely assigned before you return from a method. If you accept that (and you should, IMO) it's not clear what's left that we can help with.

Answer (score 2):

There is no corellation between the `out` parameter and your `return` value from the compiler's point of view. So it cannot and will not do any compiler magic.

The clean approach would be to split your function into the precondition and object-creation part:

```
private bool CanCreateSomeStruct(int D) {
    return D >= 0;
}

private SomeStruct CreateSomeStruct(int D) {
    return new SomeStruct(D);
}
```

And then use it like that:

```
if (CanCreateSomeStruct(D)) {
     SomeStruct SXY = CreateSomeStruct(D);
}
```

Comment: My comment may have misled you of being concerned about memory consumption. I have alternative solution to the problem and I posted here the original one for comment in relation to compiler behavior and analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The rules of the C# language don't require that the return value of any method with `out` parameters be `bool` nor assign any meaning to the return value such that validity could be determined.

For all the compiler knows both branches of your `SomeMethod` are meant to assign a real value to `SXY`. Maybe then the `bool` result is meant to indicate whether the result provided is a "live" value or one obtained by a cache. So what we currently have is a bug because we forgot to assign a value in the `false` branch and the compiler caught a bug for us!

That's why there is no *meaning* ascribed to the result of the method, and we just have a simpler set of rules to abide by - you have to definitely assign `out` parameters.

If you're concerned about memory usage by having to assign a `default(SomeStruct)` to `SXY`, perhaps the issue is that the `struct` is larger than is recommended and maybe should be a `class` instead?